# kubectl create yml config doesn't create with headers/generator v1

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to create a config map yml file from a file:

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=my-file.json -o yaml --dry-run
```

I even try with generator:

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=my-file.json --generator="configmap/v1" -o yaml --dry-run
```

but the output, doesn't contain `apiVersion` / `kind` but just `data` / `metadata`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by installing kubectl v1.9.2 rather than older version I had.